# How do I bind a tree control to a data source in VB .NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, data-binding, treeview

**Edit**:
[Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372820/how-do-you-databind-to-a-system-windows-forms-treeview-control/373177#373177)

I'm new to .NET, and I've taken on a small work project, converting an existing VB6 product to a current version of VB (its either that or learning VB6!).  This product is an internal *desktop* application (not web-based).

I need to create a new tree view, that is linked to a particular table.

Each row in the table has a parent id that links back to the table's primary key, and that defines the node hierarchy. So that relationship needs to be indicated in the databinding.

Am I able to use the standard treeview control in Visual Studio 2008, or do I need something extra to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372820/how-do-you-databind-to-a-system-windows-forms-treeview-control), this isn't possible, as the normal treeview control doesn't support databinding.

You'd need to either [programatically populate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361661/populate-treeview-from-database), or use a third-party component (I've used [Developer Express](http://devexpress.com/) in the past with C++/Delphi components, they are fantastic!).

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a tree view control using an XML file which will define your nodes or you can bind it by querying a database. Here is an article from [15 Seconds](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/041117.htm) which has a pretty thorough tutorial on using the .NET TreeView control.