# How to dynamically populate treeview (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a table with 3 columns, ID, Name and ParentID. The ID column contains running number which also serves as the primary key. ID will also be the node's **Name** properties. Name column contain string that will be the treenode's **Text** attribute, while ParentID is a column contains the node's parent ID.

This is how my table looks like:

```
ID     Name   ParentID
======================
1      A      0
2      A1     1
3      B      0
4      C      0
5      A2     1
6      B1     3
```

This table shows that node A is the parent node for node A1 and A2. ParentID equals to "0" means that the node's parent is the root node (hardcoded). E.g., Node A, B and C are root node's children.

I sort the rows by ParentID prior to populating the treeview. I populate the tree view using these two methods (TreeNode node here is the childnode that is being populated into the tree):

```
    private void SearchParent(TreeView tree, String parentID, TreeNode node)
    {
        // Post: call TraverseParent method to search parent

        TreeNodeCollection collection = tree.Nodes;

        // Search parent recursively
        foreach (TreeNode n in collection)
        {
            TraverseParent(n, parentID, node);
        }
    }

    private void TraverseParent(TreeNode potentialParent, String parentID, TreeNode node)
    {
        // Post: search for parent. When parent is found add child to parent

        // am i the parent that you're looking for?
        if (parentID.CompareTo(potentialParent.Name) == 0)
        {
            // found me! i'm your parent!

            // add child to parent
            potentialParent.Nodes.Add(node);

            // update that the parent for child has been found
            parentFound = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // i'm not your parent

            // continue to look for parent recursively
            foreach (TreeNode n in potentialParent.Nodes)
            {
                TraverseParent(n, parentID, node);
            }
        }
    }
```

All is well until I drag-and-drop the nodes by making node A the child of node C and commit the changes to the database.

Now my database table looks like this:

```
ID     Name   ParentID
======================
1      A      4
2      A1     1
3      B      0
4      C      0
5      A2     1
6      B1     3
```

The next time I run the application, it fails to populate node A1 and A2 into the tree because it could not find their parents. This is because when I sort the rows based on ParentID prior to populating the treeview, the rows are sorted like this:

```
ID     Name   ParentID
======================
3      B      0
4      C      0
2      A1     1
5      A2     1
6      B1     3
1      A      4
```

This way, my application will try to populate A1 and A2 nodes into the tree even before node A is created. Therefore the application could not find the parent for node A1 and A2.

Hence, can anyone tell me a way to fix this bug or is there a better way to dynamically populate a treeview?

Thanks.

Comment: See here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361661/populate-treeview-from-database

Answer (score 16):

You should use recursion to fill it.

The promised example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private class ItemInfo
        {
            public int ID;
            public int ParentID;
            public string Name;
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FillTreeView();
        }

        private void FillTreeView()
        {
            var items = new List<ItemInfo>()
            {
                new ItemInfo(){ID = 1, ParentID = 4, Name = "A"},
                new ItemInfo(){ID = 2, ParentID = 1, Name = "A1"},
                new ItemInfo(){ID = 3, ParentID = 0, Name = "B"},
                new ItemInfo(){ID = 4, ParentID = 0, Name = "C"},
                new ItemInfo(){ID = 5, ParentID = 1, Name = "A2"},
                new ItemInfo(){ID = 6, ParentID = 3, Name = "B1"},
            };

            FillNode(items, null);
        }

        private void FillNode(List<ItemInfo> items, TreeNode node)
        {
            var parentID = node != null
                ? (int)node.Tag
                : 0;

            var nodesCollection = node != null
                ? node.Nodes
                : treeView1.Nodes;

            foreach (var item in items.Where(i => i.ParentID == parentID))
            {
                var newNode = nodesCollection.Add(item.Name, item.Name);
                newNode.Tag = item.ID;

                FillNode(items, newNode);
            }
        }
    }
```