# How to node data from the database to treeveiw using datatable parent and child in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, treeview, nodes

How can I fetch data from the database into treeveiw and display it tree-like in the way of father and son
I tried the code below and got an inaccurate result 100%

```
    id     name        parent_id
--------------------------------------
    1      Banks        0
    2      Cars         0
    11     Bank1        1
    12     Bank2        1
    111    Acoount1     11
    112    Account2     11
    113    Account3     11
    21     Car1         2
    22     Car2         2
    23     Car3         2
```

I hope the data be like this

```
-Banks
   -Bank1
      -Account1
      -Account2
      -Account3
   -Bank2
-Cars
   -Car1
   -Car2
   -Car3
```

I get data from database by stored procedure to DataTable 
this is the code

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[GET_ALL_ACCOUNTS]

AS


SELECT * FROM ACCOUNTS
```

I want to use the data from datatable

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = account.GET_ALL_ACCOUNTS();
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{

   TreeNode node = new TreeNode(dr["id"].ToString());

   node.Nodes.Add(dr["name"].ToString());
   node.Nodes.Add(dr["parent_id"].ToString());

   treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);

}
```

I hope someone can help me

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: the problem id the data get like one type no like parent and child

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fill treeview and nodes according to parent in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823766/how-to-fill-treeview-and-nodes-according-to-parent-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Treeview doesnt handle parentid, you need to add the leaf to each node

Comment: Could you please let me know how I can do that please use the data in data table

Comment: check the possible duplicate link above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `foreach` doesn't have any tree-related logic. You have to construct a valid [`Tree`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx) based on the `id` and `parent_id` returned from the `DataTable`. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19648390/465495) logic for instance and modify it to serve your needs.