# Fill treeview with deep-rooted datalist

Tags: c#, .net, treeview, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table named Department with 3 columns [DepartmentID, ParentDepID, DepartmentName]. Each Department may have a parent Department (ParentDepID) which can have a parent and so on. I want to load this data from `sql-server` to a `treeview`.

This is an imaginary exaple of data

DepID ------ ParentID ------- Name

1----------------Null------------HospitalA
2-----------------1--------------SurgeryDepartment
3-----------------1--------------CancerDepartment
4-----------------1--------------HeartDiseases
5-----------------2--------------BrainSurgery
6-----------------2--------------ChildBirth
7-----------------5--------------UpperBrainSurgery
8-----------------5--------------LowerBrainSurgery

this can go deeper (n) times, I want to load such data to my treeview.
***What have I tried so far?*** Unfortunately I don't know how to do so, so please help me with the idea.

Comment: Well what exactly is your matter A Dynamic Tree View which you define it's structure in runtime or SQL Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            // Manage Tree View Nodes in RunTime
            // In order to manage a node you should set a key for each node
            // in your case records id's could be fine
            treeView1.Nodes.Add("RootNode1Key","Root Node1");
            treeView1.Nodes.Add("RootNode2Key", "Root Node2");
            // adds a node in runtime with title Root Node
            //Now add a Child to "Root Node 2"
            // first find the node and make a pointer to it :^)
            TreeNode FoundedNode;
            FoundedNode = treeView1.Nodes.Find("RootNode2Key", true)[0];
            // if you create a unique key for each node the find function returns
            // a tree node array with only one node and you access it like above 
            // else you retrieve many records of TreeNode
            FoundedNode.Nodes.Add("RootNode2Childe1", "Root Node2 Child 1");
            // hey now you added a child node to RootNode2
            // you want to add a child for it in depth 
            // 2 ways :
            // 1: yous find method  treeView1.Nodes.Find("RootNode2Childe1", true)[0];
            // 2: Following
            FoundedNode.Nodes["RootNode2Childe1"].Nodes.Add("RootNode2Childe1Child1", "my parent is RootNode2Childe1");
```

now if you want to remove one it's easy like following

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // i am sure you know how to add nodes now remove a node
            TreeNode FoundedNode;
            FoundedNode = treeView1.Nodes.Find("RootNode2Childe1Child1", true)[0];
            FoundedNode.Remove();
        }
```

but i suggest you search the net there are some methods and better solutions you may use a data source and then when a record added to your table and a record removed then your tree view updates and vice versa

**Offer a member ship of this community to other Iranian guys and programmers **

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the root node(the most basic one without the parent) and then add the childnodes.. This link will help you : [Populate TreeView from DataBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361661/populate-treeview-from-database)